# How to scrape multiple pages when page numbers are unordered

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape list of words from a website using BeautifulSoup. Scraping the first page is easy but to get all the pages I have to get page numbers (strings exactly) for each page which is quite hard for me because they don't start from traditional `{1-100}` or `{a-z}`, they are different for each page.

For example, [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/a/) is the page where all the links are stored for the rest of the pages in `/a/` category. Normally they would be like `a/1`,`a/2`,`a/3` but in this case they are:

```
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/a/a
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/a/a-conflict-of-interest
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/a/a-hard-tough-row-to-hoe
and so on...all the way to /english/z/{}
```

My Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = 'https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/a/a/'
head = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'
# regex = 'idiom$'

with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f_out:

    soup = bs(requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': head}).content, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class', 'hdf ff-50 lmt-15'})
    span = div.find_all('a')

    for text in span:

        text_str = text.text.strip()
        print(text_str)
        print('{}'.format(text_str), file=f_out)
```

It gets the text as expected but after that I have no idea how to parse the next pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just loop through the alphabet, grab all `href` attributes, clip the last part off of it (that's your word or expression) and then save it to a file.

Here's how:

```
import string

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "user-agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
}
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
main_url = "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/browse/english/"

for letter in letters:
    print(f"Fetching words for letter {letter.upper()}...")
    page = requests.get(f"{main_url}{letter}", headers=headers).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").find_all("a", {"class": "dil tcbd"})
    with open(f"{letter}_words.txt", "w") as output:
        output.writelines(
            "\n".join(a["href"].split("/")[-2] for a in soup[1:]) + "\n"
        )
```

Output: a file for each letter, for example, letter `a`.

```
a-conflict-of-interest
a-hard-tough-row-to-hoe
a-meeting-of-minds
a-pretty-fine-kettle-of-fish
a-thing-of-the-past
ab-initio
abduction
abo
abreast
absolute-motion
absurdity
accent
accidental-death-benefit
account-for-sth
acct
acetylcholinesterase
ackee
acrobatics
actionable
actuarial
adapting
adduce
adjective
administration-order
adoration
adumbrated
advertised
aerie
affect
affronting
afters
agender
agit-pop
...
```

Comment: Thankyou. Can u please add code for the next steps because I'm having a hard time looping through all the pages of `a-z` and getting their content.

Comment: What do you mean *next steps*? And what do you want to do with the follow links' content? Save it? Parse it?

Comment: Basically I want to scrape all the words in `/a/a` then move to next page `/a/a-conflict-of-interest` then `/a/a-hard-tough-row-to-hoe` and so on... up to `/z/zumba`, and save it to one text file.

Comment: I'm not going to give you all the code up front. Give it an honest try yourself, first. I've already nudged you in the right direction. If you get stuck, come back with a new question.